# The Secant Method: a variant of the Newton-Raphson method

Tags: matlab

I have to code the Secant Method: a variant of the Newton-Raphson method.

I have done the following:

```
function [SecantMethod] = SecantMethod(x0, x1);

%this is a variation on the Newton-Raphson MEthod, uses two inital guesses
%so that we do not have to explicitly work of the derivative of f(x).

x0 = 2;      
x1 = 1;
%the two guesses

f0 = f(x0);              
f1 = f(x1);
%two coressponding values of the function evaluated at x0 and x1

    x = x1 - (f1*((x1 - x0)/(f1 - f0)));         
    %actual Secant Method (finds x axis intercept between two guesses
end
```

When I run the code in Matlab, an error appears "Undefined function or variable 'f'."

I dont have any particular function that I want to solve I just have to code it so I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: You aren't defining `f` as an input to the function. You do take `x0` and `x1` as inputs, but immediately discard their values and replace them with 1 and 2, is that what you intended?

Comment: @David no, I just want to do a general code formula for it.

Comment: @Flow. Exactly. For the general case, you need to allow the user to pass in an arbitrary function for `f`. Also, you need a loop.

Comment: Make `f` be the first input argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a function take a function as an argument as follows:

```
function [SecantMethod] = SecantMethod(f,x0, x1);

disp(f(x0));

end
```

Then in your code:

```
%make anonymous function:
f=@(x)(x.^2);
%or:
f=@sin;

%and simply:
SecantMethod(f,1,2)
% or just:
SecantMethod(@myfucntion,1,2)
```